# Hello, how can I schedule and broadcast a pre-recorded video as a live stream in google meet?

Tags: broadcast

how can I schedule and broadcast a pre-recorded video as a live stream in Google Meet?
and can I embed it in my WordPress website?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, You can share your recorded video content as a screen share, and you can do this by scheduling it as a regular meeting through your google calendar. As per the present technical possibilities, it  is not possible to embed your (recorded) live stream in to your wordpress website.